# Developing Wcf Callback service using netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf

I stuck in a problem regarding wcf Callback service.

I am trying to develop WCF Callback service using netTcpBinding, I successfully created this Callback Service using wsDualHttpBinding but when i try to achive same thing using netTcpBinding, I am always stuck in some problem.

sometimes it is "Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it."

or "This protocol does not support netTcpBinding"

so anyone can show me how to configure web.config file and how to overcome this types of error..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without you supplying the code and config that you are currently using it is difficult to tell what is causing this error.

Maybe take a look at [Duplex Messaging](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx) and [TechNet: Creating a Duplex Service](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1735.creating-a-duplex-web-hosted-service-using-nettcpbinding.aspx).